# Execute linked OFunction

Tags: orientdb

Experimenting with OrientDB,
I'm trying to execute a linked to an instance OFunction from a function.

There is a OFunction instance with name "testFunction" and @rid #6:2;

My class has a property:

```
create property MyClass.myFunction LINK OFunction
```

My instance is:

```
insert into MyClass set myFunction = #6:2
```

Now I want to create a HTTP REST executable function that selects my instance and executes its linked function.

I see that

```
db.query('select from MyClass limit 1')[0].field('myFunction');
```

is resulting correctly to

> ```
>     "@type": "d",
>     "@rid": "#6:2",
>     "@version": 1,
>     "@class": "OFunction",
>     ...
> ```

**How to execute it by this reference?**

I know it can be executed by name with:

```
db.getMetadata().getFunctionLibrary().getFunction("test1").execute();
```

But it make no sense to search the function by string.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
String query="select myFunction.name as name from MyClass limit 1";
Iterable<ODocument> it=db.command(new OCommandSQL(query)).execute();
if(it.iterator().hasNext()){
ODocument doc1=it.iterator().next();
    String name=doc1.field("name");
    Iterable<ODocument> it2=db.command(newOCommandFunction(name)).execute();
    for(ODocument doc2:it2){
         System.out.println(doc2.getIdentity());
         }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But I trying to call the function by reference without using the name like newOCommandFunction(name).